# Disable Flyout based on VisualState

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to add/remove an `MenuFlyout` based on the `VisualStateManager`.

I have two states `Touch` and `NoTouch`. I want to set the Flyout on an Grid named `rowGrid`. And I tried different versions of the VisualStates.
E.g.:

```xml
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="TouchGroup">
    <VisualState x:Name="Touch">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="rowGrid.ContextFlyout">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MenuFlyout >
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Play" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="NoTouch">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="rowGrid.ContextFlyout" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

This however will throw an COMException (E_FAIL) as soon the `NoTouch` state is activated with the `StateManager.GoToState(...)` method. The other state will set the Flyout but without any content oly providing an empty menue.

The Grid itself is inside an `DataTemplate` of an `ListView`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Disable Flyout based on VisualState

[`Flyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Flyout) is lazy load control, it could not be initialized with `VisualState`, it need to be initialized at previous in the xaml. If you want to disable `Flyout` based on [`VisualState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate), you could change the [`MenuFlyoutPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MenuFlyoutPresenter) style hiding the `Flyout`, For detail please refer the following code.

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="rowGrid" >
    <Grid.ContextFlyout >
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="GridMenuFlyout" >
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reset"/>
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Repeat"/>
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Shuffle"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Grid.ContextFlyout>

    <Grid.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter" x:Key="MenuFlyoutPresenterShowItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter" x:Key="MenuFlyoutPresenterHideItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TouchGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="Touch">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="GridMenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPresenterShowItem}"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="NoTouch">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="GridMenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPresenterHideItem}"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try as soon I get home this evening.

Comment: It worked. However performing a right click will disable all Hover effects (including buttons). I assume It still goes in the context menu mode but displays nothing. Any Idea to prevent this?

Comment: Please try to add `<Setter Property="IsEnabled"    Value="False"/>` into `MenuFlyoutPresenterHideItem` style.

Comment: Unfortunalty this did not helped. It just disables the Flyout and its childrean (which are no longer visible)